# Why trace(123.456 - 123) gives me 0.456000000000003 in flash as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

trace(123.456 - 123)  //the output is 0.456000000000003!!!!!!
Why it gives me this strange value? i need it to output 0.456 
(my aim is to have the fraction)

Comment: `trace((123.456*1000) - (123*1000))/1000` = 0.456

Comment: Strange this is the first time I did notice!! so I think this is what I want:  
var theNumber:String=123.456;  
var theArray = theNumber.split(".");
trace(theArray [1])

Answer (score 3):

Just like 1/3rd and 1/7th cannot be expressed well in decimal notation (0.33333... and 0.142857142857... respectively), certain decimal numbers can't be represented well in binary, leading to errors like this. To solve it, try this:

```
var mynum=(123.456 - 123);
mynum=Math.round(mynum*1000)/1000;
trace(mynum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a floating point number and you can't accurately represent all numbers in floating point.

If you need a fraction, make a faction class (maybe one is built into AS already I don't know.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're dealing with a floating point number. you're going to need to round it up:

http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=778701

exert form the above link (with numbers changed):

```
var num:Number = 123.456 - 123;
num *= 1000;
num = Math.round(num);
num /= 1000;
trace(num);
```